# Why does IB show Equinor ASA under STL@OSE if the OSE symbol is EQNR?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

[Equinor ASA](https://www.equinor.com/en/investors.html#the-equinor-share) says it's listed on NYSE as an ADR under the symbol [EQNR](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EQNR?p=EQNR&.tsrc=fin-srch) and on [the Oslo Stock Exchange](https://www.oslobors.no/ob_eng/markedsaktivitet/#/details/EQNR.OSE/overview) with the symbol [EQNR](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EQNR.OL?p=EQNR.OL&.tsrc=fin-srch). However, when I try and search for "EQNR" on the Interactive Brokers' system, that leads me to ["STL@OSE"](https://pennies.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.10/index.php?action=Conid%20Info&wlId=IB&conid=12492456&lang=en). Given this is not the actual symbol for Equinor, it doesn't make sense. **Why is this happening?**

Similar problems getting OSE data through IB are mentioned [in this topic](https://www.sierrachart.com/SupportBoard.php?ThreadID=10624), but it only says that Oslo shares information based on different standards (which I don't think would include the 'correct' ticker symbol).

[This blog](https://profithunting.blogspot.com/2020/05/equinor.html) mentions outright that "Interactive brokers has Equinor as STL (Statoil)." but not the reason for it.

Answer (score -1):

If you look up 'Equinor' on IBKR, it shows 5 different Equinor securities with their respective symbols.

EQNR is the NYSE symbol.

While I didn't look it up, STL is the symbol for the stock on the OSE.

> This blog mentions outright that "Interactive brokers has Equinor as STL (Statoil)." but not the reason for it.

Look further down the menu and you'll see the Equinor security on the OSE.

Comment: I'm afraid the direct link to OSE shows that EQNR is also the symbol *there*, just not when looked up through IB

Comment: I couldn't tell you what the symbol is on the OSE because I don't subscribe to that data.  There is an EQUINOR bond on IB but again no subscription so no further info.  That's about all I have to offer.

Comment: As far as I've understood, the subscriptions only impact real-time data receipt, so even without a subscription to OSE one should see the correct ticker symbols as on the OSE?

Comment: I have never looked at foreign stocks so I don't know what one would or should see on IBKR.

Comment: Is there a material reason why IB should display different (i.e., "incorrect") information for OSE compared to NYSE? I can't think of one...

Comment: The answer to that might be found in a phone call to IB.